# Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error

> Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

My `web.config` file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WCFService1.Service">
                <endpoint address=""  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFService1.IService"  /> 
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"   contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" httpHelpPageEnabled="True"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Service.cs

```
public class Service : IService1    
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
```

Comment: Where/When are you getting the error?  During compilation? On launch? On a visit to a specific page?

Comment: on local server every thing is fine 
when publish on server i am getting this error